# Is there a right way to implement TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm learning swift and I have gone through tutorials where some developers delete the View Controller entirely and just drag in a TableViewController and start using that. While other developers in tutorials create a TableView from within the View Controller.

Is it better to delete the View Controller and add a Table View Controller or just work with a TableView within the View Controller?

Comment: Are you _only_ going to have a table view in a VC? If yes, use `UITableViewController`

Comment: What you have seen is people removing a `UIViewController` and replacing it with a `UITableViewController`. for standard usage a UITableViewController is easier to use, adding a tableView manually gives you much more control over the. for example, you might embed a tableView inside a Collection View

Comment: Using TableView in ViewController is better way than TableViewController

Comment: It's up to depend on your project type, But I suggest you- Don't delete View controller. You can handle some preloading methods in View Controller and sohw in tableView.

Comment: Ok thanks guys i appreciate the feedback !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is all about the requirement. Both are correct way. Don't be confuse.

- When you using `TableViewController` then it only behaves with the `UITableview`. i mean controller totally dedicated itself as tableview.
- When you using TableView inside `UIViewController` then you can create whole UI deign in your own way.

**Note:** As you'r new so I suggest you to go with `TableView` Inside `UIViewController` because you can achieve any type of UI with this even you can create ditto functionality(`UITableViewController`) with this but vice versa not true.

For eg.

tableView inside UIviewController

[image]

Comment: Thanks it makes more sense now, i will keep what you said in mind !

Comment: @VanoshanRamdhani check the updated answer for more clearance

Comment: I have thank you, currently doing a new table view now so going to try and grasp it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in either way. If your viewcontroller is going to have a tableview alone, then u can use a UITableViewController or else use UIViewController and set the delegates and datasource